# GitLab: при запуске пайплайна вручную пропускается job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Есть такая задача деплоя:

```yml
deploy_laravel_app_develop:
  stage: deploy
  extends: .base_deploy
  variables:
     REPLICA_COUNT: 1
     APP_PART: laravel-app
     HELM_ENV_URL: $DEV_PROJ_URL.$DEV_BASE_DOMAIN
  environment:
     name: dev
     url: "$DEV_PROJ_URL.$DEV_BASE_DOMAIN"
  tags:
     - k8s-stage
  only:
     - develop
  except:
     changes:
        - "README.md"
  needs: ["test_laravel_app"]
```

`.base_deploy`:

```
.base_deploy: &base_deploy
  image: registry.site.com/docker-images/k8s-helm/k8s-helm-master:latest
  stage: deploy
  <<: *setup_k8s   
  script:
     - cd helm/$APP_PART
     - helm dep build
     - helm ls 
     - echo $CI_ENVIRONMENT_URL
     - export DEPLOYS=$(helm ls | grep $RELEASE_NAME | wc -l)
     - set -e
     - HELM_ENV_URL=$(echo $HELM_ENV_URL | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') 
     - HELM_ENV_PUBLIC_URL=$(echo $HELM_ENV_PUBLIC_URL | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') 
     - helm upgrade --install ${RELEASE_NAME} . 
        --set-string podAnnotations.commitSHA=${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}   
        --set-string env=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}  
        --set-string replicaCount=${REPLICA_COUNT} 
        --set-string domain.name=${HELM_ENV_URL} 
        --set-string domain.publicName=${HELM_ENV_PUBLIC_URL} 
        --set-string domain.path=/${DEV_PROJ_PATH} 
        --set-string serviceAccount.name="${HELM_SA}" 
        --set domain.ssl=${TLS_SECRET}
        --set image.repository="${IMAGE_NAME}"
        --set imagePullSecrets[0].name="k8s-registry-secret"
        --wait
        --cleanup-on-fail
```

`test_laravel_app` - запускается, и отрабатывает:

```
test_laravel_app:
  stage: test
  image: $IMAGE_NAME:latest
  script:
   - cd /var/www
   - touch .env
   - touch database/database.sqlite
   - php artisan migrate --force
   - php artisan test --exclude-group optional
  variables:
     APP_PART: laravel-app
     DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
  environment:
    name: test
  needs: ["build_laravel_app"]
  tags:
   - isp-docker
```

При слиянии в develop задача деплоя (`deploy_laravel_app_develop`) запускается. А если запустить пайплайн вручную `CI/CD` > `Pipelines` > `Run Pipeline`, выбрать бранчу `develop`, то задача не запускается - ее просто нет, другими словами - пропускается. Вот так это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: почему? Можно ее каким-то способом все-таки запустить в пределах пайплайна, например добавить ручной вариант в дополнение к основному?

UPD. Есть подозрение, что это из-за

```
  only:
     - develop
```

то есть срабатывает этот триггер только при слиянии.

Comment: Приведите код `.base_deploy` скрипта от которого наследуется джоба, а также код `test_laravel_app`, наверняка проблема где-то в них. Вижу два варианта - либо не выполняется `test_laravel_app` по каким-то причинам, либо `.base_deploy` содержит условия которые не позволяют запускать наследованные джобы вручную. Больше конечно интересен `test_laravel_app` - запускается ли он? И какой у него скрипт.

Comment: @gore, добавил в вопрос

Comment: У тебя для теста и  деплоя разные `environment:` прописаны.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov спасибо. Получается, нужно при запуске определить environment=dev ?

Comment: я про `environment:` ничего не знаю, но если у тебя таски для разных сред, очевидно Гитлаб не будет их все сразу исполнять. Для MR (вероятно) `environment:` не проверяется

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov дело не в environment, так как обе задачи успешно запускаются при мерже в develop

Comment: Могу только повторить " Для MR (вероятно) environment: не проверяется"